# C++ Tic Tac Toe AI

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I am almost done with my tic tac toe game. Currently it is set up as two-player person vs. person but I know I'll have to implement a simple AI to be approved. Now I need your help with this. I know I'll have to think about it in small steps such as three "make a move" methods like

- If AI has a move in the 1st column && the two box to the right is open make a move in either box and return true
- If AI has a move in the middle && the box to the left and right is open make a move in either box and return true
- If AI has a move in the 3rd column && the two box to the left is open make a move in either box and return true

I can't understand exactly how I can implement it in my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char matrix[3][3] = { '7', '8', '9', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2', '3' };
char player = 'X';
int n;
void Draw()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Tic Tac Toe !\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void Input()
{
    int a;
    cout << "\nIt's " << player << " turn. " << "Press the number of the field: ";
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 7)
    {
        if (matrix[0][0] == '7')
            matrix[0][0] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 8)
    {
        if (matrix[0][1] == '8')
            matrix[0][1] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 9)
    {
        if (matrix[0][2] == '9')
            matrix[0][2] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 4)
    {
        if (matrix[1][0] == '4')
            matrix[1][0] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 5)
    {
        if (matrix[1][1] == '5')
            matrix[1][1] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 6)
    {
        if (matrix[1][2] == '6')
            matrix[1][2] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 1)
    {
        if (matrix[2][0] == '1')
            matrix[2][0] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 2)
    {
        if (matrix[2][1] == '2')
            matrix[2][1] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }
    else if (a == 3)
    {
        if (matrix[2][2] == '3')
            matrix[2][2] = player;
        else
        {
            cout << "Field is already in use try again!" << endl;
            Input();
        }
    }

}
void TogglePlayer()
{
    if (player == 'X')
        player = 'O';
    else
        player = 'X';
}
char Win()
{
    //first player
    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][0] == 'X' && matrix[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[0][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[0][2] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'X' && matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    //second player
    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][0] == 'O' && matrix[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[0][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[0][2] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    if (matrix[0][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (matrix[2][0] == 'O' && matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    return '/';
}

int main()
{
    n = 0;
    Draw();
    while (1)
    {
        n++;
        Input();
        Draw();
        if (Win() == 'X')
        {
            cout << "X wins!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (Win() == 'O')
        {
            cout << "O wins!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (Win() == '/' && n == 9)
        {
            cout << "It's a draw!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        TogglePlayer();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really need to learn for loops.

Comment: `else if (a == 9){ if (matrix[0][2] == '9') matrix[0][2] = player;`  Aren't you lucky that there are 9, and not 100 positions?  You've practically duplicated the code in 9 different places, where the only difference is the number and a couple of matrix indices.  Also, why are you calling `Input()` recursively??

Comment: Tip: things get simpler if you use the same placeholder value in every square.

Answer (score 2):

A computer player for a simple board game like Tic-Tac-Toe can be implemented using the [Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm, which can be improved using [α-β-pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning). Although the resulting implementation will be quite small, it might require some time to understand.

Comment: Although I think Minimax and a-b pruning might be a little to advanced topics for the OP, wikipedia explains things horribly. Here is a better explanation of Minimax applied to a tic tac toe game: http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;



    int main()
    {
/*
the chart is :
X 2 X
4 5 6
X 8 X
*/
        char Matrix[3][3] = { 'X','2','X','4','5','6','X','8','X' };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                cout << Matrix[i][j] << "     ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
/*
after this for :
X O X
4 5 6
X O X
*/
        int l = 0, m = 0, p[3] = { 0,0,0 };
        for (l; l <= 2; l++)
        {
            for (m; m <= 2; m++)
            {
                if ((Matrix[l][m]) == 'X')
                {
                    p[l]++;
                    if ((p[l]) == 2)
                    {
                        for (m; m >= 0; m--)
                        {
                            if ((Matrix[l][m]) != 'X')
                            {
                                Matrix[l][m] = 'O';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return 0;
    }
why this code dosent work?
```

Comment: An explanation along with the code helps other to understand your code. So it would be a better answer if some explaining is done about what are you trying to convey.